# Fridge Cooling Element Icing Up

Tags: refrigerator

I have a Panasonic fridge whose model number is NR-B591G.  The cooling element is icing up and hence the fridge compartment is not being kept cold.  I have changed the timer and also the thermostat in the freezer.  The blower fan is working fine.  The heating element looks fine, i.e., the coiled element is not cut, and hence assume that it is doing its job.  But if it were, the cooling element would not get iced up, i.e., defrost cycle working OK.

If the fridge is switched off and the freezer door kept open to melt the ice in the cooling element, and is later turned on, everything works fine for a few days before the problem surfaces again.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

[The authorized service people did a terrible job of identifying the problem, keep suggesting to change one part after the other, and broke a few parts in the bargain. Have stopped calling them.]

Comment: A leaking door seal can cause icing, a low Freon charge can also cause icing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will check both the seal and for low freon.  Of these two possibilities I think low freon may be more likely.